# install R packages automatically

Tags: r, installation, package, cran, install.packages

I created a R package. The `DESCRIPTION` file of this package is as follows:

```
Package: Ralgotree
Type: Package
Title: package about securiy information
Version: 1.0
Date: 2013-02-15
Author: algotree
Maintainer: algotree<dinoop@algotree.com>
Description: package about securiy information
License: GPL(>=2)
Suggests: RJSONIO,stringr,RSQLite,bigmemory,Rook,compare,plyr,lubridate,xts
Depends: RJSONIO,stringr,RSQLite,bigmemory,Rook,compare,plyr,lubridate,xts
```

It depends on other packages like `RJSONIO`,`stringr` etc.
So whenever i try to install my package in other machine using the following commands

```
R CMD build Ralgotree
R CMD INSTALL Ralgotree
```

it showing the following error messages:

```
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
ERROR: dependencies ‘RJSONIO’, ‘stringr’, ‘RSQLite’, ‘bigmemory’, ‘Rook’, ‘compare’, ‘plyr’, ‘lubridate’, ‘xts’ are not available for package ‘Ralgotree’
```

So i need to do install all packages like this `install.packages("RJSONIO")`.

Is it possible to install all uninstalled packages when we run `R CMD INSTALL Ralgotree` command?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
install.packages("mypkg", dependencies = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see that as an option in the arguments listed when I run:

```
R CMD INSTALL --help
```

The `install.packages` R function does have a "dependecies" argument which when TRUE (or the proper character vector) will gather a list of packages from the Description file and install them as well.

```
?install.packages
```